# Is there any way to "break" out of procedure?

Tags: sql, mariadb

In normal programming languages I can break out of loop under certain condition, or have multiple return statements.

If I would like to write a procedure, that checks some condition or just ends when something happens, how can I do that?

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example(input INT)
BEGIN
   IF (input < 10) THEN
       SELECT MAX(example_row) FROM example table;
       --end procedure here
   END IF;

   SELECT * FROM example_table LIMIT input;
END $$
```

I know, that this example procedure can be changed and just use multiple IF statements. I'm wondering though, is it possible to do it some other way.

Haven't found anything about it in MariaDB documentation. Is it even possible, or it allways requires to find a way around it?

Comment: You can signal an error and cancel the procedure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LEAVE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/leave/) instruction, and as explained in the documentation you just need to label your `BEGIN..END` block:

> #### Syntax
>
> `LEAVE label`
>
> [...]
> `LEAVE` can refer to the outmost `BEGIN ... END` construct; in that case, the program exits the procedure.
> [...]
> The following example uses `LEAVE` to exit the procedure if a condition is true:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN p TINYINT)
> CONTAINS SQL
> `whole_proc`:
> BEGIN
>    SELECT 1;
>    IF p < 1 THEN
>       LEAVE `whole_proc`;
>    END IF;
>    SELECT 2;
> END;
> ```